# How to set a value with useContext()?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to set my state in Context from within a nested child component, but it doesn't see my method, which I created in the context provider:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"

const Context = createContext({})

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(undefined)

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        value,
        loadValue: currentValue => {
          setValue(currentValue)
        },
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

export default Context
export { Provider }
```

In my child component I try to set it like so:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import Context from "../context/value.context"


const MyPage = ({ data }) => {
  const value = data.contentfulValue
  const { loadValue } = useContext(Context)

  loadValue(value)

  return (
    <Layout>
      ...
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyPage

export const valueQuery = graphql`
  query valueBySlug($slug: String!) {
    contentfulValue(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      ...
    }
  }
`
```

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: loadValue is not a function`

Comment: Please include all the code that is necessary to reproduce the problem. [`MRE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @AsafAviv, I've added most of my structure above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you not providing the entire app structure,

you may encounter such error when `MyPage` **is not** a child of `Context.Provider`,
therefore it suggested to add an initial value when creating the context:

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them. Note: passing undefined as a Provider value does not cause consuming components to use defaultValue.

```
const Context = createContext({ value: undefined, loadValue: () => console.log('Default function') })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Changed your code a little bit

export context as named so that you can use it

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"

export const Context = createContext({})

export default const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(undefined)

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        value,
        loadValue: currentValue => {
          setValue(currentValue)
        },
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

Use static context like following.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import {Context} from "../context/value.context"


const MyPage = ({ data }) => {
  static contextType = Context
  const value = data.contentfulValue
  const { loadValue } = this.context

  loadValue(value)

  return (
    <Layout>
      ...
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyPage
```

And Remember to import Provider at the topmost of the component tree so that any component can use it, like this

```
  <Provider>
      {/* <PageContent> */}
        <Navbar />
        <Forms />
      {/* </PageContent> */}
    </Provider>
```

if still doesn't work do tell me.